# Oculus GO Browser full screen

Tags: three.js, oculus

I would like to see a web page inside the Oculus Browser in full screen mode.
I have made a model with ThreeJS and stereo mode but i can't see the model in stereo because the browser's windos is not in full screen

Any Hints??

Thanks
Luca

Answer (score 1):

I also bought Oculus Go yesterday and I found these examples will help.
https://threejs.org/examples/?q=webvr

Below is the most simple usage of WebVR.js, a plugin script of Three.js. This worked for my Oculus Go. (but the controller was not recognized.)
https://threejs.org/examples/webvr_cubes.html

as seen in the examples, there are some points to make your scene WebVR.

- load `WebVR.js` before the script
- add a button to enter fullscreen by `document.body.appendChild(WEBVR.createButton(renderer));`
- set `renderer.vr.enabled` to `true`
- call your rendering loop function by `renderer.animate()` method (stop call it directly, as pointed out [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/WebGLRenderer.animate))
- remove `requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop)` from your render loop
- if you are moving the `position` of the camera, you have to wrap the camera by new `Three.Group` object and move the group instead. (seen in [this](https://threejs.org/examples/webvr_rollercoaster.html) exciting example)